# How do I interpret the SOM weight positions plot?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, som

I am a newbie to SOMs and am using the Matlab SOM package to examine sea level pressure over time. My 2D input array is (row x column): pressure (function of latitude and longitude) x time. When training is complete, and I plot the SOM weight positions, I get the following:
[image]

Is this correct? All of the weight position plots that I see are not so 1:1, so my plot appears strange.

Here is my code (note: code will not execute, just for conceptual purposes)

```
slp = somedata; % dim: 30200 x 1550 [pressure x time]

% Calculate mean for each location over time
mean_slp = nanmean(slp,2);

% Calculate anomalies for each location over time
slp_anom = nan((i2-i1+1)*(j2-j1+1),nfiles);
for i = 1:time
    slp_anom(:,i) = slp3(:,i) - mean_slp(i,1);
end

% Normalize data
[slp_anom2,PS] = mapminmax(slp_anom);

net = selforgmap([4 4]);
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net = train(net,slp_anom2);
```

I appreciate any and all feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## What is a Weight positions plot in the context of the SOM algorithms's training?

#### How SOM are trained

The SOM algorithm essentially computes a set of prototype/codebook vectors of the same dimension as the input data. It does so by initializing # neurons according to some rule (random, PCA, etc.) inside the input space and then shifting their positions inside the input space so as to minimize a distance metric under the constraint of a neighborhood function that determines the influence of data point in the neurons' receptive field at each iteration.

#### Weight Position Plot

The Weight Positions Plot is a **3D plot (!)** so you need to use the rotate 3D tool to be able to make sense of the map.

What you then see, depending on dimensionality, is a collection of pale-blue dots and red lines. The pale blue dots are the *projections of the neuron positions according onto the two dimensions selected for the plot* that have been shifted around the input space.

So the plot would look differently depending on which Weight Dimensions (aka. Input columns) you choose to compute the plot. *Matlab typically chooses the first two input columns.*

#### What about the water pressure?

I cannot help here as your dataset appear to be extremely wide for a simple pressure/time vector. Are the columns representing different measurement points on the globe? If so, you should ask yourself what would be gained by having a SOM model of that. What would you do when you got a new vector from a new timestamp? What would you like to do with it? What additinoal information would you gain?